# This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the OS. (Mavericks)

Tags: xcode, validation, bundle

I start by saying that I've installed Mavericks, I was curious to see the new features...
It was better to wait, because (apparently) there are no sensational changes.

Anyway, I'm trying to submit my app to the app store, but after a real hard fight with the code-signing, I have ended up with this message:

"This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the OS."

....From what I read, the only solution seems to uninstall Mavericks and go back to Mountain Lion, but I will be happy if someone else has got a alternative fix.

Answer (score 5):

After some research on Internet I've found a fix for this problem.

1) Open "App Store" and leave it for now.

2) press cmd+shift+g on your desktop and go to /system/library/coreservices/

2) Copy SystemVersion.plist to your desktop, **and duplicate the file**

3) Open the file with the right name on your desktop, not the copy, and replace the old part with this:

```
<key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
<string>12E55</string>
<key>ProductCopyright</key>
<string>1983-2013 Apple Inc.</string>
<key>ProductName</key>
<string>Mac OS X</string>
<key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
<string>10.8.4</string>
<key>ProductVersion</key>
<string>10.8.4</string>
```

4) Now copy this edited file to /system/library/coreservices, and go to "App store" application.

5) Download Xcode 4.6.3, now you can because your OsX is detected as Mountain Lion.

6) Once the download its finish, and Xcode installed, *reboot*.

7) Open your project in xcode 5 beta, if you have some .xib files, go in the file inspector, document versioning, and change development version to 4.6 instead of 5. Do this for each .xib, then close xcode 5

8) Open Xcode 4.6.3 and reopen your project. Check in the build settings that 10.9 is not present anywhere. Replace it with 10.8 or whatever you need.

9) Make clean, Build for archiving, Archive ... Cross your finger!

10) Your project should be validated now.

11) Once you uploaded your app, rename the SystemVersion.plist (copy) on your desktop, and copy it back to /system/library/coreservices. You don't need to reboot.

It's kinda a hack, but if you don't want to reinstall everything, it's the only way to go.

**P.s: after replacing SystemVersion.plist, you will notice strange behaviors in the Os, like safari that isn't working and so on, that's why I suggested to duplicate the plist file, *before* changing the os version. Anyway if you can still use terminal and "vi" to restore everything, if for some reason you didn't copy the original.**

Hope this will help someone. I've lost a day figuring out a solution ;)

Comment: How about simply changing ProductBuildVersion to 13A603 and ProductUserVisibleVersion & ProductVersion to 10.9.0 as Mark Bridges suggested. I just uploaded another app after 10.9.1 (pre-release version) did not want to work. It took me 1 minute to change everything

Answer (score 4):

Same problem with build 13A3017 on Mavericks
Switched it to 13A603 and it worked.

It's quicker to use this command in terminal and just make a note of the original build number to switch it back afterwards.

sudo nano /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist

but should probably make a copy of the file first just in case

Comment: First I was on 10.9.0 (GM seed) and it didn't work then I updated it to 10.9.1 (pre lease version through App Store). Both version gave me this error. I changed SystemVersion.plist to 13A603 & 10.9.0 and it worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem while I was using Mavericks 10.9.1 (build 13B40) and Xcode 5.1 dp. I finally solve the problem by:

1. **Use Xcode 5.0.2** instead of Xcode 5.1 dp.
2. Go to `/system/library/coreservices/` and modify the `SystemVersion.plist` using the copy/paste as @Benz 's answer. Thanks to @Benz
3. After copying and **backing** the `SystemVersion.plist`, modify the content as following:

   - mod `ProductBuildVersion` to **13A603**, which is the build number of Mavericks 10.9.0 GM.
   - mod `ProductUserVisibleVersion` and `ProductVersion` to **10.9.0**
4. Replace the `SystemVersion.plist` using the one you've modified.
5. **Restart the Xcode.**
6. Rebuild and achieve the app.
7. Submit.
8. Succeed!!!
9. Restore the `SystemVersion.plist` using the original file you've backed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mass with the **SystemVersion.plist**, here is another way to get through it on **10.10**:

After you made the archive, you can modify the .app bundle and .plist in the archive's root to match a valid accepting version. Then use the Xcode to submit it. No need to mass with the code signing or Application Loader.

If you want a simple solution and don't mind to pay for it, I've created a tool to do it with ease: https://vox.vg/xcarchiver/