# This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the OS. (Yosemite)

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I've installed beta **Yosemite**.
Now I'm trying to publish my **mac** app (the same problem with iphone apps) using **Xcode 5** (not beta). And I get this message:

> This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications
>   built with this version of the OS.

The same problem was with mavericks, look at this question:
[This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the OS. (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551428/this-bundle-is-invalid-apple-is-not-currently-accepting-applications-built-with)

It's very interesting, paradox, when Apple allows developers download and install new beta OS X, and at the same time doesn't allow publish apps.

What can we do?
Should I go back to Mavericks?

Comment: As was told in the Keynote presentation, you have the tools to start developing right away, so that you can submit your application on the day of Yosemite's release. The dev version is still in development and until you've tested your app with the released version, you're not going to know if it will function as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded publishing my app changing **/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist** file to mavericks bundle and version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dt$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
        <string>13A603</string>
        <key>ProductCopyright</key>
        <string>1983-2014 Apple Inc.</string>
        <key>ProductName</key>
        <string>Mac OS X</string>
        <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
        <string>10.9.3</string>
        <key>ProductVersion</key>
        <string>10.9.3</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Off course I will change it to original after app is published.
It works!

**NOTE:**
You must restart your computer!

Comment: That is a terrible idea, and is very likely to result in problems. Don't do that.

Comment: @duskwuff then say your solution??? It did work for me. After I published my app, I got back the origin content for Yosemite.

Comment: Don't build applications for the App Store on Yosemite. Downgrade to Mavericks if you need to do that.

Comment: Did not work for me. Updated the file and restarted XCode, this is still the case.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan Restarting Xcode is not enough, you must restart your computer!!!

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek it actually worked, I just needed to Build-->Archive again. Restarting your computer with wrong `SystemVersion.plist` sounds dangerous.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan If you make new archive without restarting computer it won't work, you will get same message "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently..". Restarting computer with old systemVersion won't make any trouble, you need to replace with your original systemVersion and restart again.

Comment: This is just asking for trouble. There's a reason the submission process checks against the OS version.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mass with the **SystemVersion.plist**, here is another way to get through it on **10.10**:

After you made the archive, you can modify the .app bundle and .plist in the archive's root to match a valid accepting version. Then use the Xcode to submit it. No need to mass with the code signing or Application Loader.

If you want a simple solution and don't mind to pay for it, I've created a tool to do it with ease: https://vox.vg/xcarchiver/

Comment: I like the idea. I tried to submit my Mac OS App with this beta version of EL Capitano but i couldn't do with the SystemVersion.plist modified for some reasons and i went and did the way you wanted. That worked well and easy. Thanks

Comment: Generally I think it's bad practice to sort of advertise your app like this on SO.  That said, I bought Zhi-Wei's tool, and it rocks.